# cannot figure out how to populate a dictionary from an xml file

Tags: python, xml

I am brand new to python. I am working in 2.7 and I'm trying to parse an XML file to populate a dictionary and keep track of how many times the variable-name is used (the name will change, hence the dictionary), it also needs to skip the number and colon in the variable-name. I know I need to pull it as an element so I can manipulate it but I am not sure how. Please help. This is what I have back tracked to along with a section of the XML code.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse(sample.xml)
root = tree.getroot()

d = {}

for iec-source in root:

    variable_code = variable.find('variable-name')

if variable_code.text == #varibale is in dictionary add count

else #add to dictionary and add count
```

[xml picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GBIF.png)

Comment: Can you explain a little more what the keys/values are in the dictionary?

Comment: The `.find` and `.findall` methods use XPATH strings. The etree documentation has a good section on building XPATH strings, but basically I suspect you will need `for variable_name in root.findall(".//variable-name")`

Comment: they will be the variable-name from the xml file.  so example 5:Inspection, Inspection would be added to the dictionary and counted 1 time.  i figured that would be the easiest way to count what variable-name is used and how many times it appears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first, you're going to want to pull all the variable_name nodes. The `.find` method will return the *first* node that matches the specified XPATH. The `.findall` method will return an array of *all* nodes that match. Next you're going to want to process the text. If you *know* that *all* variable names have a colon, you can use `.split()` on the string. Finally you can use `if key in dict.keys()` to check if a key exists.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("sample.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

dict = {}

# Loop through all nodes with tag <variable_name>
for variable_name in root.findall(".//variable_name"):

    text = variable_name.text    # Get the raw text from the xml

    variable = text.split(":")[1]    # Splits the text into an array
                                     # ["#","VARIABLE"]
                                     # keep the second element

    if variable in dict.keys():
        dict[variable] += 1    # Increment the count for that variable
    else:
        dict[variable] = 1     # Add the new variable to dict, initialize to 1
```